# FCM doesn't work on ios in the flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using fcm for pushing notification to my app , using real device for it and follow the full integration for APNs , the notification arrive only when the app is open , but if the app is on background or terminated I got this error :

> [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in
> application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: no valid
> “aps-environment” entitlement string found for application
> nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C7] Query fired: did not
> receive all answers in time for iid.googleapis.com:443
> nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C14] Query fired: did not
> receive all answers in time for app-measurement.com:443

this is my initState and I put it in main , notice that I'm using bloc and splash screen in my code if this can cause the problem

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        showToast(msg: message['notification']['title']);
        //_showItemDialog(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) async {
     
    });
  }
```

Note : this problem just in ios but in android everything is ok

So can anyone help me !

Comment: Have you enabled pushnotification in Capabilities. and also tick remote notification in background mode capabilities

Comment: yes i did it before